# Checking if row items of two columns in a pandas dataframe are the same

Tags: python, pandas

Given a dataframe `C` with columns `time` and `session` I want to check if the row item in each column matches and then do some operation if true. I'm wondering if there is a vectorized solution to this, currently this is what I'm doing:

```
for i in range(len(C['time'])):
    if C['time'][i] == C['session'][i]:
        # do something
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can index your original dataframe with your equality condition and then operate on the result:

```
C.loc[C['time'] == C['session'], ] = ...result of some operation...
```

Comment: Question, why do you need the `, ` in `C.loc[C['time'] == C['session'], ]` doing `C.loc[C['time'] == C['session']]` appears to give the same result

Comment: In this case, you can probably do without the comma. The comma's good in cases where you might want to do something to a particular column. If, for example, you wanted to assign a new value to the column `value`, you'd do `C.loc[C['time'] == C['session'], 'value'] =...`